# meta tag inside body

Tags: facebook-apps, meta-tags

I wrote page http://www.consumerguide.com. The facebook debuger complains that there is a meta tag inside the body. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.consumerguide.com%2F

But on viewing the page source there is no such meta tag inside the body tag.

What do I need to change for removing this error?

Comment: Check the messages the facebook API provides, check there what it needs to be done and if you cannot manage it, come back here with questions.

Answer (score 0):

Document type does not allow element "noscript" inside "head". Move all "noscript" tags inside "body". And that should work.

See the very first error at [http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.consumerguide.com).